# Azure app services

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services, azure-webjobs

With the changes made in the type of services in azure, I am not able to correctly make a mobile service cloud based back end and use it in my android app.
I followed the guide from 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/

the above link, but after the changes in azure services (it has changed its mobile app service to web app service) I am not able to understand how to create a cloud based back end (basically a to-do list) and connect it with my andorid app.

Can someone please help?

Comment: As the description in your link, `Azure Mobile Services` has been superseded by `Azure App Service Mobile Apps` and is scheduled for removal from Azure. What do you mean changing the service? Did you change the Mobile App to Mobile Service? And you want to connect your original Android app to the mobile service from mobile app?

Comment: did you read the question, please do read it once again.
Change in services mean that the mobile app service have been replaced by web services and thus there have been many changes in some specific options.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/
This is what I am talking about.

Comment: The link you provided, is about Mobile Service to Mobile Apps, but your question's description looks like you are migrating mobile Apps to Mobile Service. Which is sharked me, so I have to confirm first. One more question I need to confirm is, which language are you using in the backend server? C# or Node.js?

Comment: I am using node.js
There is no way now that I can create a new mobile service under Azure mobile services now as that has already been removed so the only possibility that remains is that I create a new web+mobile service and build the app
So my question was hoe do I create a mobile back end wit the revised services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the structure has changed in Mobile Apps in App Services from the original Mobile Services. Now, the Mobile Apps in Node.js, is acutally a web application base on Expressjs framework, and all the mobility functionalities are integrated as a middleware of Express named [azure-mobile-apps-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node).

And as you are following https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/ to migrate your mobile service to mobile apps. And after migration, you don't need to do any change on your android client app. Azure will automatically complete the config for you clients connection.

And after migration, you will find and config your new mobile apps on [new Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com).  And the original table operation scripts have been migrate to **Easy Tables**, and the original custom APIs scripts have been migrate to **Easy APIs**.
[image]

Actually, the migration guide post which you are following has detailed explained the changes. And about developing on the Mobile Apps in Node.js, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/ for more info.

Comment: Following the steps can we run the app on GENYMOTION emulator?

Comment: Actually, I haven't tested on GENYMOTION, but in my opinion, the emulators are almost the same. I have tested in VS emulator for Android and physics devices. So I think it should work fine on GENYMOTION too.

Comment: Yeah after testing the app is up and running on any emulator.
But can you tell me how to check the elements added in the table created.?

Comment: By default, the data is store in a Azure SQL Database. As a migration Mobile App, you can find an App setting `MS_SqlConnectionString` by clicking `Settings`=>`Application Settings`, and scroll to `App settings` section. The setting string contains your Azure SQL Database info, leveraging which you can connect to your Database via SSMS or some other SQL Server workbench.

Answer (score 2):

The article has the answer right at the top, you should use Mobile Apps and follow this tutorial instead: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/